# Value of MCITP: Database developer/administrator

Tags: sql-server, certificate

I'm targeting these two certificates. But I don't really know that how they affect my CV, and, of course, my salary.

Are they truly valuable? Do they make differences in your work and your position before and after you get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's several parts to this question:

**But I don't really know that how they affect my CV,**

The cert is like icing on the cake, but nobody just wants to eat icing.

If it's the best thing on your CV, then it's a help.  For example, if you're fresh out of college and you have zero experience, then these certifications show that you've learned a technology that's new and relevant.  Colleges don't teach the same information footprint that these certs cover - college degrees are great for the theory behind what you're doing, and the certs are a little more applicable to what you're doing hands-on as a developer or DBA on that particular technology.

It's not as good as real experience, though.  If you've got, say, 2 years of hands-on database development or administration, then that probably trumps a cert in most cases.

**and, of course, my salary.**

It's not going to matter significantly.  If you have the choice between doing four weekends of consulting versus four weekends of studying for the cert, then you're going to make more out of the consulting.  In theory, the certs will raise your billable rate, but if you're even asking that question, you're not at the point of your career where this is going to make a difference.

Instead, go ask your manager what they wish they could accomplish in the next two months.  Tell 'em you're willing to take on their pet project in your side time to help both of you.  Deliver some new piece of code, some new utility, clean up a database, save them licensing, whatever it is, and you'll be more likely to get a raise than if you go get a cert.

And when you're picking side projects, pick something that you can put on your resume.  "Reduced licensing costs by $120k through a successful server consolidation project" says a lot more to employers than "MCITP."

**Are they truly valuable?**

Things that are easy to get are not valuable.  Some certs (like the Microsoft Certified Master) are valuable.  The ones you can get in a few weekends of studying - not so valuable.

**Do they make differences in your work**

No, but the studying that you do to PREPARE for these exams will make a difference in your work.  In the course of studying, you'll learn tips, tricks and features that you can leverage in your development/DBA work.

**and your position before and after you get it?**

If you think you're going to get a raise simply by showing your MCITP, you're on the wrong track.  Ask your manager for a frank and honest evaluation of your work.  Tell them that you want to make sure your career keeps moving, and that you'd like their advice on what you should do next.  If you don't like your manager, ask your mentor - find a programmer who's already doing what you wish you were doing, and ask 'em how they got there.  It's probably not by getting a cert.

Comment: your answer is truly valuable!

Comment: Be careful about getting certs unrelated to your chosen field. I know hiring managers who cull resumes which list too many certs.

Answer (score 5):

They may be the tie breaker between you and another candidate for a job, which is far more relevant these days.

Your experience is irrelevant although the exams are easier the more you have.

The biggest issue is the detractors and nay-sayers: "easy", "worthless", "only Microsoft" etc

- If it's so easy, why not have it?
- If it's so worthless, why do so many people go for it?

It shows interest in learning and self-development, which is not as common as you think. As well as being prepared to invest your own time and money into your career.

BTW, I'm a SQL Server 2000 MCDBA since 2002, with 6 of 7 MCSE exams too: I must upgrade mine...

Edit, Feb 2018

I think they are devalued now. Experience and knowledge matter more now

Answer (score 4):

it depends on where you are in your career.

For entry level positions then it's definitely a yes.  The courses cover enough material so that you'll know your way around SQL Server, but certs wont make you an expert.  Having a certification also shows a basic level of competency.

If your further along in your career & you work as a SQL DBA or developer & have been with SQL for a few versions then they're probably less valuable if all your looking to do i to get up-to-date with the differences & new features.

Nonetheless if you want to go down the path of becoming a certified trainer, or your organization wants to become a microsoft partner, then certification is a must.

Then there's the *I'm a member of an exclusive club bragging rights*.  According to [these published microsoft numbers](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/mcp/certified.mspx)  there's only 228 certified database administrators for 2008 and 3,233  certified developers for 2008.

Answer (score 4):

Some good points are made here. I agree about certification being the icing on the cake--it definitely makes a cake better than one with no icing, but a cake without icing can still hold it's own. As was mentioned, nobody wants to eat JUST the icing. Also note that icing tends to go on last.

I recently got a job at a very data driven SaaS company as a SQL Server DBA. I had experience as a SQL Developer and no certification. That said, I indicated I was willing to learn and now they're having me do the cert under pain of death. Why? As was pointed out above, if your company is a MS partner they REQUIRE certified people. I don't know the specifics of the deal but those who say the cert isn't valuable (in terms of raw $$) may not be thinking beyond their own desks. I'm also getting a bonus for doing the cert because it really is resulting in immediate benefit to the company, not to mention the knowledge I'm acquiring in preparing for the exams. It doesn't in any way make up for lack of experience I agree, but the point is I already have some under my belt so for me the cert is valuable and needed.

The whole experience thing is really key for a DBA role, I'd say more so than a developer or sysadmin role. Not very many companies are going to hand the keys to their precious data over to a newbie. Just try searching job sites for "Junior DBA" if you don't believe me. Developers and Sysadmins can be pretty darned powerful and important but there tends to be more of them and more need for junior roles. If you aren't a DBA, have no SQL experience and want in then I suggest becoming a developer or sysadmin first. Try to get as much hands on with SQL Server as possible in that job, then you'll be in a position to transition to DBA.